# wifi - maximum number of pending replies per connection has been reached

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

Sometimes, my wifi internet connection gets interrupted which i can see when the leds in the wifi modem goes off.

Now, when the connection resumes (i mean, the green led starts glowing in the modem), i try to connect to it by using `network-manager` client,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo nmcli nm wifi off
sudo nmcli nm wifi on
nmcli d wifi connect myName password myPass iface wlan0
```

It throws error as,

```
     ** (process:21073): WARNING **: async_got_type: could not read 
properties for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2: 
    The maximum number of pending replies per connection has been reached
        Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2' failed in libnm-glib
```

I had to reboot my ubuntu 14.04 machine to resolve this.

Normally, I would prefer my machine to connect automatically, when the interrupted network connection starts working...

Comment: Ran into same issue. This exact issue is mostly ignored in the NetworkManager mailing list and IRC channel. I've been trying to get help from them for a good while now. There is no further information pertaining to this.